# How might I use a concatenated string from a sub-query in the next query up?

Tags: sql-server

I have a list of companies, divisions, and contracts something like this.

```
Company  Division   Contracts
-------  --------   ---------
ABC      Avril      0000111
ABC      Blocky     0000247
DEF      Blocky     0000346
GHI      Franklin   0000123
GHI      Franklin   0000156
JKL      Owned      0000458
JKL      Owned      0000567
MNO      Owned      0000672
MNO      Owned      0000672
```

I am trying to make it so that my query will return any rows where a Division has more than 1 contract associated with it and these are also under the same company.

The case above should return just

```
Company  Division   Contracts
-------  --------   ---------
GHI      Franklin   0000123
GHI      Franklin   0000156
JKL      Owned      0000458
JKL      Owned      0000567
```

Is it possible in the query below to use the "DISTINCT(concat(division, contracts))) > 1" in the next query up the line instead of "division", or am I going about this completely wrong.

```
SELECT DISTINCT company, division, contracts
FROM inventory 
WHERE contracts in (
    SELECT DISTINCT contracts 
    FROM inventory
    WHERE division in (
        SELECT DISTINCT division
        FROM inventory
        GROUP BY family HAVING 
        count(DISTINCT(concat(division, contracts))) > 1
    )
    GROUP BY contracts HAVING 
    count(DISTINCT(concat(company, division))) > 1
)
ORDER BY division
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of the Window function Dense_Rank

```
Declare @YourTable table (Company varchar(50),Division varchar(50),Contracts varchar(25))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('ABC','Avril','0000111'),
('ABC','Blocky','0000247'),
('DEF','Blocky','0000346'),
('GHI','Franklin','0000123'),
('GHI','Franklin','0000156'),
('JKL','Owned','0000458'),
('JKL','Owned','0000567'),
('MNO','Owned','0000672'),
('MNO','Owned','0000672')

Select A.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Join  (Select *,Cnt  = Dense_Rank() over (Partition By Company,Division Order By Contracts ) From @YourTable) B
   on  A.Company=B.Company and A.Division=B.Division and Cnt>1
```

Returns

```
Company Division    Contracts
GHI     Franklin    0000123
GHI     Franklin    0000156
JKL     Owned       0000458
JKL     Owned       0000567
```

Comment: Thank you in that this worked with the data set I provided, but I must have abstracted it too far from my actual data set as I come up with extra rows of unwanted data. Thank you for your help though.

Comment: @Vyff Just let me know if I can help

Comment: Solved, I had been adding extra necessary filtering in a WHERE clause, but outside of the JOIN clause that you created. This was causing rows to be filtered after the table creation.